# Change bootstrap carousel indicator

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I used bootstrap 5 carousel. I want to change indicator icon to round.

```
            <div class="carousel-indicators">
              <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
              <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
              <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
            </div>
```

How to change that